# executeUpdate in createQuery does not update my database

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, createquery

```java
public void updateUserState(User user) {
        Session sess=getSession();
        sess.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
        String queryStr = "update User usr set usr.logCount = :logCount , usr.isLocked = :isLocked , usr.lastLogin = :lastLogin where usr.userId=:userId";
        Query query=null;
        query = sess.createNativeQuery(queryStr);
        query.setParameter("logCount", user.getLogCount());
        query.setParameter("isLocked", user.getIsLocked());
        query.setParameter("lastLogin", user.getLastLogin());
        query.setParameter("userId", user.getUserId());
        query.executeUpdate();
}
```

This is my code. This does not update mu user table in database , neither does this throw any error. It reflects the correct value till set parameter but after executeUpdate, I cannot see any update in my table. It would be really nice if anyone of you can tell me, where am I going wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see call `Session.flush()` in the end.

Comment: I have tried this as well, but Session.flush() also did not help.

Comment: Do you run this code inside transaction? `Transaction txn = session.beginTransaction(); ... txn.commit();`

Comment: Yes I am doing that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing) flush type `MANUAL` assume:

> The Session flushing is delegated to the application, which must call `Session.flush()` explicitly in order to apply the persistence context changes.

So, you should explicitly call `Session.flush()` in the end of your method.

Also your `updateUserState` method should be ran inside a [transaction](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#transactions):

```java
Session sess = getSession();
sess.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
Transaction txn = sess.beginTransaction();
// ...
query.executeUpdate();

sess.flush();
txn.commit();
session.close();
```